# why is my chart showing only errors?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

here's my SSRS chart::

[image]

I've checked the sql statements from which this chart is generated. i've run the statements in SSMS, and they return data without errors.

also, i've used sql profiler to intercept the exact statements that is being sent to sql server, and i've re-run these statements without problems.

**what might be some other causes of error in the expression of the source of a chart on ssrs 2008 r2?**

this is in design mode:

[image]

these are called **chart series labels**

Comment: did u write any expression for `Data Points`?

Comment: do you mean LABEL? yes it is =Sum(Fields!MoveOuts).Value

Comment: remove the sum...just keep this and check `=Fields!MoveOuts.Value`

Comment: i just tried that, no luck!

Comment: @PraveenNambiar anything else?

Comment: Does fields!moveout has an integer value ?

Comment: yes definitely because i am able to run this query from SSMS

Comment: try removing =Fields!MoveOuts.value as well and put a hardcoded value. First a number and then a string. see if it gives any clues

Comment: Have you set a custom format string for the point labels?

Comment: @GayanSanjeewa i did what you suggested and got the same result

Comment: @RealityGone no i have not. any other ideas?

Comment: It's strange that you got the error for hardcoded values as well. Perhaps you may be getting the error even without anything in the expression box.Hard to tell without looking at the report. Try removing and re-adding the labels.

Comment: @GayanSanjeewa yes great point. i think there might be a different or deeper issue. the curve that it drew on the graph is the standard microsoft chart advertisement, it has nothing to do wtih my data

Comment: @GayanSanjeewa btw funny thing is that the server for once is giving me no errors on this report!!!

Comment: @RealityGone any other suggestions hyou may have?

Comment: What is the value expression on the chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your SQL otherwise you would not see a report, let a lone a chart on the report. The issue is then in the expression.

The best method for putting in data labels is to use the pre-defined **keywords**. I suggest you enter `#VALY` as text in the properties box. For more keywords see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207017.aspx).

**Add guide:**

1. Open the *label properties* dialog box.
2. Under the *label text*, see below, change the `«Expr»` to `#VALY`.

*Dialog box example from google and SearchSQLServer*

[image: Dialog box example from google and SearchSQLServer]